# java regular expression @path param optional

Tags: java, regex, rest, path, rs

i need help with a java regular expression, I need to accept HTTP request at these paths:

```
categories
categories/533446dd2cdc5af82a027d9e,

533446dd2cdc5af82a027d9e stay for @Path param called "id";
```

I'm working on this regular expression:

```
categories(\/)?([a-z0-9]{0,25})?
```

but it's not working, can you help me?
thanks guys :)

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's not working, i need to insert in the expression the "id" to set value of @PathParam

Comment: did you try `categories(/[a-z0-9]{0,25})?`

Comment: is there really a comma at the last?

Comment: @AvinashRaj thanks but i need to set @ PathParam value from regular expression, how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following example :

```
String str1 = "categories/533446dd2cdc5af82a027d9e";
String str2 = "categories";
String pattern = "categories(/[a-z0-9]{0,24})?";
System.out.println(str1.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(str2.matches(pattern));
```

Output :

```
true
true
```